# Google Analytics: how can you hide data from a view?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am creating a custom view for a customer, and I don't want to show all the data.

Is it possible to hide the data of a section (for example, Audience) on a custom view?

[image]

Comment: No. An Alternative would be to create a custom report with the relevant metrics and have it emailed to him in regular intervals. But you cannot hide menu items, and it would be pointless as most reports can be reconfigured to display data from other sections.

Comment: I managed to include only data for some specific events inside the Behaviour menu item. I wonder why it's not possible to hide data from other sections.

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood. You can filter almost any data via view filters. You cannot remove a menu item and the associated reports. If you use exclude/include filters you will remove the complete hit, but if you want to remove only part of the information you can use an advanced filter to overwrite  data fields with a dummy value (not all fields are available for filtering, though).

Comment: I refuse to believe that Google Analytics doesn't allow to hide the Real-Time and Audience and Acquisition data in a custom view.

Comment: There must be a way to provide a customer with a view that only reports some specific events.